# how to call multiple xaml file in aspx, and how to convert xaml to xap

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-3.0

I am silverlight 3.0 with .net framework 4.0. I want to create a wen based application using silverlight am using multiple xaml files, to call xaml files i need to make xap file how to convert xaml to xap in clientBin, abd how to use multiple xaml files (Like company.xaml, NewEvent.xaml, mainPage.xaml etc.) in aspx page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To "convert" XAML to XAP, make sure
   you are working in Visual Studio
   2010, and click **Build**. This will
   generate a XAP.
2. To have multiple XAP, create multiple Silverlight projects
3. To use XAP in website, create new (or use existing) ASP.NET Web project; add Silverlight project references in Project Properties page > Silverlight; then the compiled XAP will appear in ClientBin folder of web project
4. To use multiple XAP in same ASP.NET page (ASPX), just copy the Silverlight HTML object tags few times and change the paths. You can display multiple XAPs in same ASPX.